# Are questions relating to personal and family journaling (both physical and digital) appropriate for genealogy.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion

I'm interested in keeping a personal journal, digitally that includes digital photos etc.

Are questions relating to personal and family journaling (both physical and digital) appropriate for genealogy.stackexchange.com?

As a follow on question: if this isn't the correct location, please direct me to a better one.

Comment: My first opinion is no, but as I think about it, I'm not sure. (This is the correct location)

Comment: Fixed. Thanks Rebecca.

Comment: I like this topic and understand that Family journaling is coming back in style!

Answer (score 9):

It seems like it would be too early to exclude these questions, and they do seem very much a part of Genealogy and Family History. After all, keeping such journals and documentation now may help future generations in their research of their ancestral lineage.

Answer (score 8):

During the proposal, we originally named the site "Genealogy" but then decided it was more than that and called it "Genealogy and Family History".  Family History includes more than just tracing ancestors. It also includes the telling and recording of family stories.

Personally, I think this site can include genealogy questions, family history questions, and personal and family journalling.

There is actually an [Association of Personal Historians](http://www.personalhistorians.org/), and their interest overlaps with Genealogy and Family History so much, that I think it would be a shame to exclude them.

The next question would be whether we should include [Scrapbooking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrapbooking), which is defined by Wikipedia as: "a method for preserving personal and family history in the form of a scrapbook."

But I'm fine with what the majority think on this.

If we did decide to include these, we should ensure that standard tags are defined for their use.

Comment: My first fear when I read this question was the term 'scrapbooking' coming up, but maybe their posts can lean more towards using terms related to journaling and history and less towards a crafting stream.

Comment: I think journaling about family history is fine, but journaling about your current day to day life is a bit off topic. For example sitting down, talking with and listening to family stories with relatives and the journaling about those times and the stories would fit. A journal about your hiking trip wouldn't fit. Scrapbooking in itself is fine, think of a family scrapbook about the trip over from Italy  with photos of the ship and people, etc. I think would be on topic. A scrapbooking about a recent camping trip wouldn't. In general if the subject matter is family history I think its OK.

Answer (score 4):

I think questions on interviewing relatives and organizing and publishing are appropriate, which I think might use a lot of the same techniques.