# Should we allow "scrapbooking" questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Following-up with this previous [answer](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7/52), should we allow "scrapbooking" questions along with personal/family [journaling](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2/52) questions?

The Wikipedia definition:

> a method for preserving personal and family history in the form of a scrapbook

would seem to lend itself well to this format, but I am not 100% sure myself.

Comment: Do you have an example question?

Comment: @Luke - not directly. It's just a follow-up to the previous links listed

Comment: This topic has bounced between extremely general and (perhaps) too specific forms. Is the appropriate form of the question "Should GFH include questions about methods and techniques for presenting or publishing family histories?" That might encompass scrapbooking (use of acid-free paper), blogging (how to embed a timeline), and ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a matter of course, scrapbooks/scrapbooking and journals/journaling should not be excluded from the scope of the site.

Scrapbooks and other family memorabilia are recognized methods of passing information and tradition among family members. Scrapbook are or become "artifacts," which are recognized and important resources for family historians.

This does not preclude the notion that some questions about scrapbooking and journaling could be poorly constructed, etc. and so closed or down voted.